# jQuery horizontal scrolling on click not working

Tags: jquery, horizontal-scrolling

I know there are several questions on this topic but I cannot figure out why this is not working...

I have a website that is in horizontal format, I have 2 arrows at the bottom and would like to be able to click the right arrow to scroll right and the left to scroll left.

This is the html:

```
<div class="arrows">
    <div class="arrow-left">
        <a href="">
          <img src="/assets/images/arrow-left.svg"/>
          </a>
      </div>
    <div class="arrow-right">
        <a href="">
          <img src="/assets/images/arrow-right.svg"/>
          </a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

and this is the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var scrollTimer;
  var $document = $(document);
  var scrollOffset = 20;
  var maxScrollOffsetLeft = $document.width() - $("body").innerWidth();

  function scrollContent(scrollDir) {
      var scrollArgs = {
          scrollLeft: ($document.scrollLeft() + (scrollOffset * scrollDir))
      };
      $("html").animate(scrollArgs, 50);
  };

  function scrollLeft() {
      if ($document.scrollLeft() > 0) {
          scrollContent(-1);
      }
  };

  function scrollRight() {
      if ($document.scrollLeft() < maxScrollOffsetLeft) {
          scrollContent(1);
      }
  };

  function scrollStop() {
      clearInterval(scrollTimer);
  };

  $(".arrow-left").on("mousedown", function () {
      scrollTimer = setInterval(scrollLeft, 60);
  }).on("mouseup", scrollStop);
  $(".arrow-right").on("mousedown", function () {
      scrollTimer = setInterval(scrollRight, 60);
  }).on("mouseup", scrollStop);

});
```

I am not getting any console arrows but it is not working, all that happens when I click on the arrows is that it seems that the page is getting refreshed or something. Anyone know why? Or have a better solution?

Thank you all :)

Comment: If I remove the href (I tried) I am not able to click on the arrows...

Comment: Ok, change the `<a href=''` to `<a href='#'` - look in your network tab - a *link* to another url when that url == "" links to the same page - so clicking on the `<a>` is redirecting you to your same page - which explains your *"is getting refresh or something[sic]"*.

Comment: with the # I get no refresh but still no scroll. And I have mousedown now but it also doesn't work with the click function - I don't really mind which one I use as long as it works